# Alguém me ajuda a subtrair uma lista de outra?

Tags: python, funções, lista, python-requests

Gente sei que é simples mas estou me batendo aqui pra fazer isso, gostaria de fazer uma subtração de listas da seguinte maneira

```
lista_inicio = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
lista_chamada = ["1", "2"]
Lista = []

print(lista_inicio)
print(lista_chamada)
lista = lista_inicio - lista_chamada < **Como faço essa parte?**
print(lista)
```

Comment: Inicialize `lista` com uma cópia superficial de `lista_inicio ` assim `lista = lista_inicio[:]`  e itere por `lista_chamada ` removendo de `lista` seus elementos e `for e in lista_chamada: lista.remove(e)` veja o exemplo: https://ideone.com/CHnaym

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça verificação pela `lista_inicio` e armazene todos os elementos que não estão na `lista_chamada`:

```py
def compara_chamada(lista_i, lista_c):
    return [i for i in lista_i if i not in lista_c]

lista_inicio = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
lista_chamada = ["1", "2"]
# é aqui que a mágica acontece: verifico todos da lista_inicio e armazeno
# exceto os que aparecem na lista_chamada
lista = compara_chamada(lista_inicio, lista_chamada)
print(lista)
```

Comment: muito obrigado cara, agora vou complicar mais um pouco e tu me ajuda a fazer essa função "magica" ?

Comment: Agora digamos que a lista tenha valores repetidos por exemplo ["1", "1", "2", "3"]
quando eu excluo a lista chamada e vao todos os numeros 1 e todos os 2 certo ?
como faço pra ir apenas 1 numero ao invés de ir todos os numeros iguais

Comment: Sobre criar a função, editei a resposta. Sobre valores repetidos, não entendi... Os valores repetidos estão na inicio ou chamada?

Answer (score 0):

As operações que você está querendo, são operações de conjunto. O python tem uma estrutura de dados própria para isso chamada `set()`

Veja abaixo:

```
>>> lista_inicio = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
>>> lista_chamada = ["1", "2"]
>>> print(set(lista_inicio) - set(lista_chamada))
{'9', '4', 'A', 'Q', '8', '5', 'K', 'J', '7', '3', '6'}
```

Caso você precise que o resultado seja uma lista, use:

```
print(list(set(lista_inicio) - set(lista_chamada)))
```

Claro que você pode atribuir a uma variável

```
lista_resultado = list(set(lista_inicio) - set(lista_chamada)))
```

Quanto aos itens repetidos, a estrutura do `set` já trata isso

```
>>> lista = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
>>> print(set(lista))
{1, 2, 3}
```

Veja abaixo rapidamente como acrescentar itens no `set()`

```
>>> conjunto = set([1, 2, 3])

>>> print(conjunto)
{1, 2, 3}

>>> conjunto.add(4)

>>> print(conjunto)
{1, 2, 3, 4}

>>> conjunto.add(4)

>>> print(conjunto)
{1, 2, 3, 4}

>>> conjunto.add(1)

>>> print(conjunto)
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Perceba que o segundo `4` e, posteriormente, o segundo `1`, **não** foram incluídos.

**Em tempo**: A resposta marcada como solução em 22/07/2021, não é performática.